# TinyMCE 4.7.11 custom styles using styleselect - what does the 'attributes' argument do?

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce

I'm writing a plugin to add custom formats to TinyMCE using styleselect.

I've scoured the documentation and hundreds of examples covering the inline, block, selector, classes, and wrapper arguments.

I can't find a single example of how to use "attributes" argument.

Both WordPress and TinyMCE say this:

"Name/value object with attributes to apply to the selected elements or the new inline/block element."

Part of my array deals with external links - namely to add classes that help with Google analytics.

```
array(  
    'title'         => 'Link Resource',
    'selector'      => 'a', 
    'classes'       => 'smart-link-external smart-link-resource',   
    'wrapper'       => false,
),
```

I was hoping to use the attributes argument to add things like rel="external".

I'm not sure this is even the intended use for the argument, let alone how to configure it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure this is even the intended use for the argument

**Yes, it is.** Use the `attributes` option to add HTML attributes (e.g. `class`, `title`, etc.) to the *generated* or target element (e.g. `span`).

So based on your example:

```
array(  
    'title'         => 'Link Resource',
    'selector'      => 'a', 
    'classes'       => 'smart-link-external smart-link-resource',   
    'wrapper'       => false,
),
```

When you select a link (i.e. an `a` element) in the TinyMCE editor, and then apply the *Link Resource* style/format to that element/text, TinyMCE will add `smart-link-external smart-link-resource` to the element's/link's `class` attribute:

```
<!-- Before you applied "Link Resource" -->
<a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a>

<!-- After you applied that style/format -->
<a class="smart-link-external smart-link-resource"
  href="http://google.com">WordPress</a>
```

> I was hoping to use the attributes argument to add things like
>   rel="external".

So if you change your code to:

```
array(  
    'title'         => 'Link Resource',
    'selector'      => 'a', 
    'classes'       => 'smart-link-external smart-link-resource',   
    'wrapper'       => false,
    // The change: Add the `attributes` array.
    'attributes'    => array(
        'title' => 'My Link Resource',
        'rel'   => 'external',
    ),
),
```

The link's markup would change to:

```
<a class="smart-link-external smart-link-resource"
  title="My Link Resource" href="https://wordpress.org/" rel="external">WordPress</a>
```

So as you can see, the link/element now has these two new attributes: `title` and `rel`.

---

**[DEMO]** Try this [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjgqjQ?editors=1010#0): Select the text/link "TinyMCE" in the heading in the TinyMCE editor, then choose "Link Resource" from the "Formats" drop-down menu in the editor's *second* toolbar row. Then go to "View → Source code" or "Tools → Source code" via the *first* toolbar row.

The corresponding JS/TinyMCE code:

```
{
    title: 'Link Resource',
    selector: 'a',
    attributes: {
        title: 'My Link Resource',
        rel: 'external',
        'class': 'smart-link-external smart-link-resource'
    },
    wrapper: false
}
```

Comment: You're a rock star! ... Thanks for the quick reply - there are zero examples out there ... Face palm for me not thinking 'array'.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you. =) But sorry for the typo — it's `wordpress.org` and not `google.com`..